# What does "/" mean in an input statement?

Tags: sas

The sas code is

```
data coat;   
    input category high1-high3 / low1-low3;   
    array compare{2,3} high1-high3 low1-low3;   
    do i=1 to 2;   
       do j=1 to 3;   
          compare{i,j}=round(compare{i,j}*1.12);   
       end;   
    end;   

run;
```

In the statement `input category high1-high3 / low1-low3;` I don't know the meaning of the slash`/`.  Does it mean the columns are high1-high3 and rows are low1-low3?

Comment: Does the slash mean  mean  change the line?

Comment: See Method 2 in the documentation on Reading Multiple Records to Create a Single Observation: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002001051.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `/` moves the pointer to the next line on the file you are reading. Your piece of code doesn't make sense, though. There's no reason to use an `input` statement without a `datalines` or `infile` statement.

See below for an example of how your `input` statement would read raw data:

```
data coat;
  input category high1-high3 / low1-low3;
  datalines;
1  2  3  4
5  6  7
8  9  10 11
12 13 14
;
run;
```

SAS reads the first line into the first four variables and the second line into the next three variables. The end result is a dataset with 2 rows and 7 variables.

Comment: 6 variables, not 7. The values of `4` and `11` will be missing from your dataset.

Comment: There are 7 variables in the `input` statement.

Comment: Sorry, yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

/ is used an input statement to to move pointer to the next line on the input flat file. This is used when your input data is present on two or more lines and you want to create a single observation out of it.

Example:

```
data out;
input StudentID $ Name $ / Age Gender $;
datalines;
S100 John
24 M
S101 Michelle
25 F
;
run;
```

Output dataset:

```
StudentID  Name        Age  Gender
     S100  John         24      M
     S101  Michelle     25      F
```